# Insert a string within another string based with probability based on location

Tags: python, string, random, probability

I'm working in Python and I would like to insert a string within another string at a random location. But I would like the choice of random location based on a probability distribution that favors certain locations more than others. Specifically, I want to insert more strings towards beginning of the original string and less towards the end.

For example, if the insertion string is **"I go here"** and the original string is **"this is a test string and it can be long."** I want to insert the insertion string at a random location in the original string. But if I do it say 100 times, I would the result **"I go here this is a test string and it can be long"** to be the result more number of times than **"this is a test string and it can be long. I go here".** I want to be able to tune the probability distribution.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the random.gauss() function.
It returns a random number with gaussian distribution.
The function takes two parameters: `mean` and `sigma`. `mean` is the expected mean of the function outputs and `sigma` is the standard deviation- 'how far the values will be from the mean'.
Try something like this:

```
import random

original_str_len = 7
mean = 0
sigma= original_str_len  # just an example.

r = random.gauss(mean, sigma)  # random number- can be negative
r = abs(r)
insertion_index = int(r)
```

Notice, this code is not perfect but the general idea should work.
I recommend you to read more about the Gaussian Distribution.